# GetEvalStr method not implemented ServiceStack.Redis RedisClient

Tags: c#, redis, servicestack

I'm trying out the `ServiceStack.Redis` library for connecting to Redis and for some reason I cant create an instance of the `RedisClient` class, whenever I do...

```
RedisClient redisClient = new RedisClient();
```

I get...

```
Method 'GetEvalStr' in type 'ServiceStack.Redis.RedisClient' from assembly 'ServiceStack.Redis, Version=3.9.37.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' does not have an implementation.
```

The weirdest part is it stops me from debugging the method containing that line. i.e. when I try to call the method which contains it...

```
Cache.Get(key)
```

I cant step through it.

Any ideas?

FYI im using the latest version available on NuGet (version 3.9.37).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a dirty dll, where you're using an old version of `ServiceStack.Redis.dll` which does not match the implementation in v3.9.37 version of `ServiceStack.Interfaces.dll`.

First make sure you have all of ServiceStack's components updated. If that doesn't work clear out all your existing NuGet packages of ServiceStack (i.e. delete the `/packages` folder and `packages.config` file) and re-install them from NuGet again.

Comment: This answer is correct, but it is not always wise to update to the latest `ServiceStack` components. I learnt the hard way, once I updated to `ServiceStack 3.9.69` my builds failed. After troubleshooting then I realise `ServiceStack.ContainerAdapter.Ninject` does not support `ServiceStack.Common` greater than `3.9.59`. Eventually I had to rollback all my updates.